# Identify a book (probably Children's Book) by cover art

Tags: story-identification, books

I have the cover art for a book, probably a children's book, but no idea what the title of the book is.

[image]

If someone could help me identify this book, or even offer details that they might remember about it, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: You could have Googled the Image and you would have gotten the same result

Comment: @Shevliaskovic I did not know you could google an image, which means no, I could not have done that before finding out that was a thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name of these books/ this series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155822/what-is-the-name-of-these-books-this-series)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I [used TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/search/89815f3c4ca8edf7f3d7cfa47102b4231d508973/), which allows you to find similar images to a given image (they describe it as a “reverse image search engine”), to find similar illustrations.

About the fifth result down is an Amazon link for a book called **Dealing with Dragons**, by Patricia Wrede. This is the description [from the Amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JECGGM):

> Cimorene, princess of Linderwall, is a classic tomboy heroine with classic tomboy strengths--all of which are perceived by those around her as defects: "As for the girl's disposition--well, when people were being polite, they said she was strong-minded. When they were angry or annoyed with her, they said she was as stubborn as a pig." Cimorene, tired of etiquette and embroidery, runs away from home and finds herself in a nest of dragons. Now, in Cimorene's world--a world cleverly built by author Patricia C. Wrede on the shifting sands of myriad fairy tales--princesses are forever being captured by dragons. The difference here is that Cimorene goes willingly. She would rather keep house for the dragon Kazul than be bored in her parents' castle. With her quick wit and her stubborn courage, Cimorene saves the mostly kind dragons from a wicked plot hatched by the local wizards, and worms her way into the hearts of young girls everywhere.

Does that sound familiar?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 13):

From a quick Google Image Search it appears to be from Dealing with Dragons by Patricia C Wrede:

Quick Summary/Review of the story:

> Princess Cimorene hates deportment and advanced curtseying, but she's denied lessons in magic, swordsmanship, or cooking--so she runs away and applies for a job as Dragon's princess. She keeps cave, treasure, and kitchen in order, but has trouble convincing the rather dim Prince Therandil that she really doesn't want to be rescued. It's fortunate that she succeeds, since a renegade Dragon has betrayed his kind to the Wizards, and only Cimorene can save her Dragon, Kazul, from being destroyed, in the end, Kazul becomes King of the Dragons, while Cimorene becomes King's Cook and Librarian. Along the way, she learns to fireproof herself, consort with witches, read magic tomes, outwit djinns, and instill pluck in a fellow princess. Smoothly written and ingenious fantasy. Both Cimorene and her dragon are firmly drawn, tough-minded females who refuse to conform to stereotypes (being female doesn't prevent a dragon from becoming king). The touch of feminist persuasion only adds to the story's charm.

[image]

Source: https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/patricia-c-wrede/dealing-with-dragons/
Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dealing_with_Dragons

It also appears to be a series of five books.